# Uncaught Typeerror in Bundled Code for Angular 2 Using Gulp

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, gulp, typeerror

First off - thanks for your help! I've built a web app using Angular 2 and am in the final process of launching in production, but am experiencing an error in bundling with Gulp. There seems to be a lot of documentation around the specific Typeerror I'm experiencing, but nothing that I've seen really matches my use case and position in the process.

Specifically, the actual bundling process itself returns no errors when running the following command:

```
sudo gulp
```

However, when validating whether the code can run on my localhost, the following error is returned:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

and the file where this error is referenced is app.min.js, which is the output file of my wholly bundled code.

After debugging the issue further, from what I can tell, there's potentially some disconnect in how modules are being evaluated, but I can't seem to put a thumb on the root cause of the issue, or a solution to the issue. That's where I could use the community's help - figuring out how to address the issue where 'prototype' cannot be read.

gulpfile.js:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const del = require('del');
const cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const liveServer = require('gulp-live-server');
const plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
const runSequence = require('run-sequence');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const sysBuilder = require('systemjs-builder');
const tslint = require('gulp-tslint');
const tsc = require('gulp-typescript');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const tsconfig = require('tsconfig-glob');

const tscConfig = require('./tsconfig.json')

// Development

gulp.task("devmin", function () {
    return gulp.src([
        'wwwroot/js/jquery.js',
        'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js',
        'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
        'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
        'wwwroot/js/toastr.js',
        'wwwroot/js/moment.js',
        'wwwroot/js/typescript.js',
    ])
    .pipe(concat('site.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/js'));
});

// Clean the distribution directory

gulp.task('clean:dist', function() {
    return del('wwwroot/dist/*');
 });

// Clean the JavaScript distribution directory

gulp.task('clean:dist:js', function() {
    return del('wwwroot/dist/js/*');
 });

// Clean the CSS Distribution directory

gulp.task('clean:dist:css', function() {
    return del('wwwroot/dist/css/*');
 });

 // Clean library directory

gulp.task('clean:lib', function () {
  return del('wwwroot/lib/**/*');
 });

// Compile TypeScript to JS 

gulp.task('compile:ts', function () {
  return gulp
    .src(tscConfig.filesGlob)
    .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler: function (err) {
        console.error('>>> [tsc] Typescript compilation failed'.bold.green);
        this.emit('end');
      }}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(tsc(tscConfig.compilerOptions))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/dist/app'));
});

// Generate SystemJS-based builds

gulp.task('bundle:js', function() {
  var builder = new sysBuilder('wwwroot', 'wwwroot/systemjs.config.js');
      console.log("-----------------------------Start");
  return builder.buildStatic('app', 'wwwroot/dist/js/app.min.js')
    .then(function () {
      console.log("-----------------------------Deleting");
      return del(['wwwroot/dist/js/**/*', '!wwwroot/dist/js/app.min.js']);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error('>>> [systemjs-builder] Bundling failed'.bold.green, err);
    });
});

// Minify JS bundle

gulp.task('minify:js', function() {
  return gulp
    .src('wwwroot/dist/js/app.min.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/dist/js'));
});

gulp.task('compile:sass', function() {
    // concat and minify global scss files
    gulp
        .src('wwwroot/css/global/*.scss')
        .pipe(plumber({
            errorHandler: function (err) {
                console.error('>>> [sass] Sass global style compilation failed'.bold.green);
                this.emit('end');
            }}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({ errLogToConsole: true }))
        .pipe(concat('styles.min.css'))
        // .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/dist/css/global'));

    // minify component specific scss files

    gulp
        .src('wwwroot/css/*.scss')
        .pipe(plumber({
            errorHandler: function (err) {
                console.error('>>> [sass] Sass component style compilation failed'.bold.green);
                this.emit('end');
            }}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({ errLogToConsole: true }))
        // .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/dist/css/component'));
});

// Concat and minify CSS

gulp.task('minify:css', function() {
    // concat and minify global css files
  gulp
    .src('wwwroot/css/*.css')
    .pipe(concat('styles.min.css'))
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/dist/css'));

        // minify component css files

  gulp
    .src('wwwroot/css/component/*.css')
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/dist/css/component'));
});

// Copy dependencies

gulp.task('copy:libs', function() {
    gulp.src([
        'node_modules/rxjs/**/*'
    ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/lib/js/rxjs'));

    gulp.src([
        './node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
        './node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
        './node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js',
        '.node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
        './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
        './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        './node_modules/moment/moment.js',
        './node_modules/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js',
        './node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js',
        './node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
        './node_modules/toastr/package/toastr.js'
    ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/lib/js'));

    gulp.src([
        './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
        './node_modules/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.min.js',
        './node_modules/toastr/toastr.js',
        './node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js',
        './node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/dist/index.js',
        './wwwroot/systemjs.config.js'
    ])

    .pipe(concat('vendors.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/lib/js'));

      // copy source maps
    gulp.src([
        './node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.map',
        './node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js.map',
        './node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js.map'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/lib/js'));

    gulp.src([
        '.node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.*',
        './node_modules/bootstrap-toggle/css/bootstrap-toggle.css',
        './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css',
        './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css.map',
        './node_modules/bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.css',
        './node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css.map',
        './node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
        './node_modules/glyphicons-halflings/css/glyphicons-halflings.css.map',
        './node_modules/glyphicons-halflings/css/glyphicons-halflings.css',
        './node_modules/toastr/package/toastr.css',
        './node_modules/toastr/package/toastr.css',
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/lib/css'));


    gulp.src([
        "./node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/FontAwesome.otf",
        "./node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot",
        "./node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg",
        "./node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf",
        "./node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff",
        "./node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2",
        "./node_modules/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot",
        "./node_modules/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg",
        "./node_modules/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf",
        "./node_modules/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff",
        "./node_modules/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2"
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/dist/fonts'));

    gulp.src(['./node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/**/*']).pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/lib/js/angular-in-memory-web-api'));

    // handle all angular

    return gulp.src(['node_modules/@angular/**/*'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/lib/js/@angular'));
});

// Copy static assets

gulp.task('copy:assets', function() {
    return gulp.src(
        [
            '*.json',
            '*.html',
            '*.css',
            '!*.ts',
            '!*.scss'
        ],
            { base: '' })
            .pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/dist'))
});

// Update the tsconfig files based on the glob pattern

gulp.task('tsconfig-glob', function() {
    return tsconfig({
        configPath: '.',
        indent: 2
    });
});

// Watch the source files for changes, then trigger recompilation

gulp.task('watch:src', function() {
    // gulp.watch('src/**/*.ts', ['scripts']);
    // gulp.watch('src/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch('./**/*.ts', ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch('./**/*.scss', ['styles']);
});

gulp.task('test', ['compile:specs'], function() {
    // gulp.watch('src/**/*.ts', ['compile:specs']);
    gulp.watch('./**/*.ts', ['compile:specs']);
});

gulp.task('lint', ['lint:sass']);

// gulp.task('clean', ['clean:dist:js', 'clean:dist:css', 'clean:lib']);

gulp.task('copy', function(callback) {
//    runSequence('clean:lib', 'copy:libs', callback);
    runSequence('copy:libs', callback);
});

gulp.task('scripts', function(callback) {
    // runSequence(['clean:dist:js'], 'compile:ts', 'bundle:js', 'minify:js', callback);
    runSequence('compile:ts', 'bundle:js', 'minify:js', callback);
});

gulp.task('styles', function(callback) {
//    runSequence(['clean:dist:css'], ['compile:sass', 'minify:css'], callback);
    runSequence(['compile:sass', 'minify:css'], callback);
});

gulp.task('build', function(callback) {
    runSequence('copy', 'scripts', 'styles', callback);
});

gulp.task('buildnocopy', function(callback) {
    runSequence('scripts', 'styles', callback);
});

gulp.task('default', function(callback) {
    runSequence('build', callback);
});
```

systemjs.config.js:

```
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
var map = {
  'app': 'dist/app',
  'rxjs': 'lib/js/rxjs',
  '@angular': 'lib/js/@angular',
  'zone.js': 'lib/js/zone.js',
  'moment': 'lib/js/moment',
  'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'lib/js/angular-in-memory-web-api',
  'typescript': 'lib/js/typescript',
};

// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
var packages = {
  'app': { main: 'main', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'zone.js': { main: 'zone', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'symbol-observable': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'angular-localstorage': { defaultExtension: "js"},
  "angular-in-memory-web-api": { main: "index.js", defaultExtension: "js" },
  'moment': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
};

var packageNames = [
  '@angular/common',
  '@angular/compiler',
  '@angular/core',
  '@angular/forms',
  '@angular/http',
  '@angular/platform-browser',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
  '@angular/router',
  '@angular/testing',
  '@angular/upgrade',
];

// add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
  packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
});

System.config({    
  map: map,
  packages: packages
});
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "wwwroot",
    "outDir": "wwwroot/dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot/node_modules",
    "node_modules",
    "typings",
    "wwwroot/lib"   
  ],
  "filesGlob": [
    "wwwroot/app/**/**/*.ts",
    "typings/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Please let me know if I need to provide any more documentation. Thanks!

Comment: prototype is not a function

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 0):

I know there was a point where the minification/uglification of Angular 2 with gulp-uglify was broken.

Try removing the uglify step and see if that helps your case.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the insight! So I just removed the uglification part, and while it didn't eliminate the typeerror, something just occurred to me. Could it have something to do with the fact that some of my services are an extension of a base service that I use?

Comment: Hmm... theoretically that should not be an issue that I'm aware of... but you could try removing references to those and see if that works out.

Comment: Yeah true, at this point I'm just trying to rack my brain to try something I haven't done yet. I just removed the extensions and that didn't change anything, but worth a shot!